# how to choose the gcc version when apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, g++, cross-compiling

I want to setup a cross compile environment on Linux for my embeded board. My linux host is ubuntu12.04 32bit.

I have already update the gcc and g++ to 4.8, but when I apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf, it always automatically get the 4.6 one which can not satisfy my target program building.

```
root@alcht:~# gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

root@alcht:~# g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

 root@alcht:~# apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 The following extra packages will be installed:
  binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf cpp-4.6-arm-linux-gnueabihf cpp-arm-linux-gnueabihf g++-4.6-arm-linux-gnueabihf
  gcc-4.6-arm-linux-gnueabihf gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf libc6-armhf-cross libc6-dev-armhf-cross
  libgcc1-armhf-cross libgomp1-armhf-cross libstdc++6-4.6-dev-armhf-cross libstdc++6-armhf-cross
  linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc gcc-4.6-locales cpp-doc g++-4.6-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf gcc-4.6-doc
  libstdc++6-4.6-dbg-armhf-cross gcc-4.6-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf libmudflap0-4.6-dev-armhf-cross
  libgcc1-dbg-armhf-cross libgomp1-dbg-armhf-cross libquadmath-dbg-armhf-cross libmudflap0-dbg-armhf-cross
  binutils-gold autoconf automake1.9 libtool flex bison gdb-arm-linux-gnueabihf gcc-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf cpp-4.6-arm-linux-gnueabihf cpp-arm-linux-gnueabihf g++-4.6-arm-linux-gnueabihf
  g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf gcc-4.6-arm-linux-gnueabihf gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf libc6-armhf-cross
  libc6-dev-armhf-cross libgcc1-armhf-cross libgomp1-armhf-cross libstdc++6-4.6-dev-armhf-cross
  libstdc++6-armhf-cross linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross
```

how to choose the gcc version when apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf?

If I get the g++4.8 directly, it cannot locate the package:

```
root@alcht:~# apt-get install gcc-4.8-arm-linux-gnueabihf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-4.8-arm-linux-gnueabihf
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-4.8-arm-linux-gnueabihf'
```

Should I update the sourcelist? or something wrong with my gcc dependency?

Comment: Your package managing system does not have `gcc-4.8-arm-linux-gnueabihf` package. It has `gcc-4.6-....`. To install a particular version, add package repository to `apt-get` with the package or install from sources. Your upstream does not provide that package.

Comment: Ubuntu 12 is kind of old and out of support. GCC 4.6 and 4.8 are in the same situation. You should probably use something more modern. At minimum, find a distro that provides GCC 5.0 or 6.0.